# Android SyncAccount / SyncAdapter add more options to account screen

Tags: android, synchronization, preferences, android-syncadapter

How to add more options to sync account screen?
Ex. how frequently do sync like in evernotes account settings, etc..

Answer (score 1):

In your authenticator.xml you can specify an attribute

```
 android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
```

Then simply create the preference screen just like any other.